# polymorphism with types for common fields

Tags: f#, polymorphism

Is this question solvable through **functional idiomatic** approach, could **generics** or **discriminated unions** be the answer?

Is it possible to have polymorphism with passing different types to a function while the function is consuming some common fields.

Idea is to be able to call and reuse the function with different types and use the common attributes/fields.

```
type Car = {
    Registration: string
    Owner: string
    Wheels: int
    customAttribute1: string
    customAttribute2: string
}

type Truck = {
   Registration: string
   Owner: string
   Wheels: int
   customField5: string
   customField6: string
}


let SomeComplexMethod (v: Car) = 
    Console.WriteLine("Registration" + v.Registration + "Owner:" + v.Owner + "Wheels" + v.Wheels
    // some complex functionality
```

**Use**

```
SomeComplexMethod(car)
SomeComplexMethod(truck)
```

---

**Edit**

Following the answer. Is it possible to specify the type of the incoming `v` since JSON serializer asks for the associated type. If Car was supplied as input, Car will be output, If truck as input truck will be output.

```
let inline someComplexFun v  =
    let owner =  (^v: (member Owner: string)(v)) 
    let registration = (^v: (member Registration: string)(v))
    // process input

    use response = request.GetResponse() :?> HttpWebResponse
    use reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    use memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd()))
    (new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<Car>)).ReadObject(memoryStream) :?> Car
```

if truck was the input `v`

```
(new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<Truck>)).ReadObject(memoryStream) :?> Truck
```

Comment: "some complex functionality" for example?

Comment: maybe you looking for `interface`?

Comment: SRTPs can do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters

Comment: @FoggyFinder yes interface for example but I think it's OOP, what's the functional idiomatic way to handle these?

Comment: @CaringDev thanks for the link but I didn't get that, can you please provide an example with my code

Comment: is it a generic that I'm looking for?

Comment: @CaringDev just for print - yes, so it depends on "some complex functionality"

Comment: How we can provide an example if you say nothing about your task?

Comment: what is `func SomeComplexMethod`? Did you mean `let`?

Comment: Thanks @s952163 for the hint, got confused between languages, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is usually called structural (or duck) typing. It can be done via interfaces  and object expressions in F# (the accepted way) or via SRTPs. The link @CaringDev provided gives you a quick rundown, but obviously you can find many more examples. Please read [this](http://fssnip.net/7Ts) and [this](http://fssnip.net/7Tr). For your specific example it will depend how much control you have over the original types.

It's easy to define another type that includes the fields that you might want. Then your function (I found it interesting btw, that you so much want to go for a functional solution but named it a method...) should just take ANY type that has the required fields/properties. Generics won't work for you in this case, as you need to constrain to a subset of types. But once you have such a function, which uses statically resolved type parameters (SRTPs) you're good to go:

```
type Car = {
    Registration: string
    Owner: string
    Wheels: int
    customAttribute1: string
    customAttribute2: string
}

type Truck = {
   Registration: string
   Owner: string
   Wheels: int
   customField5: string
   customField6: string
}

type Bike = {
    Owner: string
    Color: string
}

type Vehicle = {
    Registration: string
    Owner: string
}

let inline someComplexFun v  =
   let owner =  (^v: (member Owner: string)(v)) 
   let registration = (^v: (member Registration: string)(v))
   {Registration = registration; Owner = owner}

let car = {Car.Registration = "xyz"; Owner = "xyz"; Wheels = 3; customAttribute1= "xyz"; customAttribute2 = "xyz"}
let truck = {Truck.Registration = "abc"; Owner = "abc"; Wheels = 12; customField5 = "abc"; customField6 = "abc"}
let bike = {Owner = "hell's angels"; Color = "black"}
someComplexFun car //val it : Vehicle = {Registration = "xyz";
                   //Owner = "xyz";}
someComplexFun truck //val it : Vehicle = {Registration = "abc";
                     //Owner = "abc";}
someComplexFun bike //error FS0001:
```

The `Vehicle` type is defined but it could be anything. Then `someConplexFun` is defined that can take any type, that has `Owner` and `Registration`. It has to be `inline` and its type signature is:

> val inline someComplexFun :
>     v: ^v -> Vehicle
>       when  ^v : (member get_Owner :  ^v -> string) and
>             ^v : (member get_Registration :  ^v -> string)

You can pass any type that has `Owner` and `Registration` fields, and it will return a `Vehicle` but of course you can just print it out or return a tuple, etc. For the `Bike` type, since it doesn't have `Registration` this function will fail.

Comment: 1. awesome, this is cool. Please educate me more on this carat `^`symbol/operator with some documentation links, and is it some kind of auto generated dynamic getter and setter going on in here, (Reflection?). +1 for quoting on what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: 2. Why it has to be inline? meaning the code is essentially duplicated for each call? Let's say if `someComplexFun car` `someComplexFun car`is called twice, meaning copies of the `someComplexFun` code will be substituted in the place of the call

Comment: Yes, it has to be inline, the .NET type system doesn't support this kind of types and type constraints out of the box. Instead the F# compiler will resolve it for you at compile time for each type (so not run time as in dynamic typing, hence it's safe) and it  won't need reflection either (so it's fast).

Comment: For reference please search SO for F# and SRTP, and check out the [F# Language Spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.0/FSharpSpec-4.0-latest.pdf) (again search for statically resolved) together with the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters). It was put in place so F# can do generic arithmetic (basically it means you can do use + with int, float, bigint etc.

Comment: `It can be done via interfaces and object expressions` I've seen the interface example in here but curious about object expressions?

Comment: Object expression are just a way to create objects without the need to create a type first. If you have an interface you can just create a sort of anonymous type based on an already existing one that uses it. It's nice because it cuts down on the boilerplate. It's basically the implementation of the interface. See [Object Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/object-expressions) and [Fsharp for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/object-expressions/).

Comment: one more thing please, is it possible to know the type of incoming `v`? see my edit please. Any lateral thinking welcome.

Comment: It's a roadblock for me, and I've been thinking all day, is it solvable or should we adopt a different strategy? I can put up another question for this if you say?

Comment: here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49567600/polymorphism-for-both-function-inputs-and-outputs

Answer (score 3):

This looks like the classical use case for object inheritance, or perhaps an interface. The difference is that an interface provides only methods (including properties, as they are methods under the hood), while a base object (abstract or concrete) can also provide fields.

In your case an interface might be appropriate:

```
type IVehicle =
    abstract Registration : string
    abstract Owner : string
    abstract Wheels : int

type Car (_r, _o, _w) =
    member customAttribute1 : string
    member customAttribute2 : string
    interface IVehicle with
        member Registration = _r
        member Owner = _o
        member Wheels = _w

type Truck (_r, _o, _w) =
    member customField5 : string
    member customField6 : string
    interface IVehicle with
        member Registration = _r
        member Owner = _o
        member Wheels = _w

let someComplexMethod (v : IVehicle) =
    stdout.WriteLine "Registration: " + v.Registration +
                     "\nOwner: " + v.Owner +
                     "\nWheels: " + v.Wheels
```

**EDIT:** You can do it without OOP by using a discriminated union, and several record types:

```
type VehicleBase =
    { Registration : string
      Owner : string
      Wheels : int }

type CarAttributes =
    { customAttribute1 : string
      customAttribute2 : string }

type TruckAttributes =
    { customField5 : string
      customField6 : string }

type Vehicle =
    | Car of VehicleBase * CarAttributes
    | Truck of VehicleBase * TruckAttributes

let processVehicle v =
    stdout.WriteLine ("Registration: " + v.Registration +
                      "\nOwner: " + v.Owner +
                      "\nWheels: " + v.Wheels)

let someComplexMethod = function
    | Car (v, _) -> processVehicle v
    | Truck (v, _) -> processVehicle v
```

Comment: thanks dumetrulo, question is, is this idiomatic way in functional programming world? because I see more of OOP in it? How about discriminated unions or generics, just throwing words out there.

Comment: @App2015 F# is primarily functional PL so if OOP- approach better fit for task just use it.

Comment: The non-OOP way of doing this would be using a discriminated union to differentiate the various vehicle types but in this case it might be more complicated than using OOP…

Comment: I like the way you used discriminated unions, please allow me some time to test and come back to you after working out my specific example.

Comment: I've an error, can you please execute at your end, screenshot -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy7vq.png

Comment: Sorry, my bad, please enclose the parameters of ``WriteLine`` in parentheses ``()``.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways how to solve this problem. Besides the already shown solution, i would use lambda functions or a new datatsructure, to solve this problem.

The idea with a lambda is. Instead of a value you expect a function as an argument that returns the needed value. As an example:

```
let printInformation registration owner wheels obj =
  let reg    = registration obj
  let owner  = owner obj
  let wheels = wheels obj
  printfn "Registration: %s Owner: %s Wheels: %d" reg owner wheels

let car = {Registration="CAR"; Owner="Me"; Wheels=4; customAttribute1="A"; customAttribute2="B"}
let truck = {Registration="TRUCK"; Owner="You"; Wheels=6; customField5="A"; customField6="B"}


printInformation
  (fun (obj:Car) -> obj.Registration)
  (fun obj -> obj.Owner)
  (fun obj -> obj.Wheels)
  car

printInformation
  (fun (obj:Truck) -> obj.Registration)
  (fun obj -> obj.Owner)
  (fun obj -> obj.Wheels)
  truck
```

But the whole idea is that you create such a function once for each type, and use partial application.

```
let printCar = 
  printInformation
    (fun (obj:Car) -> obj.Registration)
    (fun obj -> obj.Owner)
    (fun obj -> obj.Wheels)

let printTruck =
  printInformation
    (fun (obj:Truck) -> obj.Registration)
    (fun obj -> obj.Owner)
    (fun obj -> obj.Wheels)

printCar car
printTruck truck
```

Based on this you can create a dispatch function, if you wish

```
let print obj =
  match box obj with
  | :? Car   as c -> printCar c
  | :? Truck as t -> printTruck t
  | _              -> failwith "Not Car or Truck"

print car
print truck
print "FooBar"
```

Now the first ttwo works, but you lose type-safety. The third one compiles, but creates a runtime exception.

Working with lambdas is good enough if you only have 1-3 values, but if you need more values, then it can become cumbersome. Another idea would be to create your own data-type for your function, and provide conversation functions instead.

```
type Information = {
  Registration: string
  Owner:        string
  Wheels:       int
}

let printInfo (info:Information) =
  printfn "Registration: %s Owner: %s Wheels: %d" info.Registration info.Owner info.Wheels
```

The advantage. Now you relay on data instead of types. You can basically print any type as long you can create an Information record out of it. So its just a matter of providing a single transformation function for each type.

```
let carToInformation (car:Car) : Information = 
  {Registration=car.Registration; Owner=car.Owner; Wheels=car.Wheels}

let truckToInformation (truck:Truck) : Information = 
  {Registration=truck.Registration; Owner=truck.Owner; Wheels=truck.Wheels}

printInfo (carToInformation car)
printInfo (truckToInformation truck)
```

Sure, you can once again create a dispatch function based on this idea. Its up to you, but my personal approach i would create an Information type and use explicit conversation instead.

In my opinion it is the easiest to understand, and also the most useful one, as you can easily print any type this way as long you somehow can provide the needed data. And your different types don't need to share a common interface with pre-defined fields that have some special logic in it.

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around your solution, can you please explain this signature `let printInformation registration owner wheels obj` and then this call `let reg    = registration obj`, what's going on in here?

Comment: @App2015 `registration` is a lambda function that you pass an object, and its purpose is to return the "Registration" information as a `string`. Instead of hard-coding `obj.Registration` this way you can create a lambda function that returns the registration from a type. The advantage is, that you are more flexible how the Registration can be created. Same is true for `owner` and `wheels`, those are lambda function that you call, that return the apropiate `string` or `int`.

Comment: so essentially you are passing an object along with it's getter lambdas to printInformation

Comment: Yes, some getters that know how to get the information. By partial application you can create specific implementations for different types.