# Polymorphism for both function inputs and outputs

Tags: f#, polymorphism

Polymorphism for inputs was [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49526861/polymorphism-with-types-for-common-fields) using **functional idiomatic approach** and now looking forward to solve it for return types that involved a JSON serializer which actually demands to know the type of the record.

Input parameters were enforced to have some specific fields as mandatory and the solution allowed to pass different types as long as the field members existed. Solution was referred to as SRTP or structural (or duck) typing.

Now I've a roadblock where this function is essentially a web service call which returns the latest JSON schema based on the type of the object passed. I pass in mandatory fields (Registration, Owner, Wheels) only and the server returns the original mandatory data along with the custom fields and both types (Car, Truck) have different kinds of JSON schemas.

The block is with JSON serializer that needs to know the type of the object being passed and the type has to be **hard coded** in order to serialize.

So in a way function has both polymorphic inputs and outputs.

```
type Car = {
    Registration: string
    Owner: string
    Wheels: int
    customAttribute1: string
    customAttribute2: string
}

type Truck = {
   Registration: string
   Owner: string
   Wheels: int
   customField5: string
   customField6: string
}


let inline someComplexFun v  =
    let owner =  (^v: (member Owner: string)(v)) 
    let registration = (^v: (member Registration: string)(v))
    // send the mandatory fields to server to fetch rest of the custom fields.

    use response = request.GetResponse() :?> HttpWebResponse
    use reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    use memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd()))
    (new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<Car>)).ReadObject(memoryStream) :?> Car
```

Now this last line essentially will change if Truck type was passed

```
(new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<Truck>)).ReadObject(memoryStream) :?> Truck
```

**Note:** 
Now If there's a lateral approach using a different functional idiomatic way, I'm flexible to choose a different path. As long as function can not only receive and return these two specific types.

P.S. Is reflection an answer to this?

Comment: Well, the very definition of a function is taking in an input of a certain type and generating an input of the same or another type. Doesn't DataContractSerializer retain info about the type and do generics? If not your life is a bit difficult, and maybe you need to switch to another serializer. But first I would break up your your function, at least into two, serialization should be separate from everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If necessary, you can check the type info and pass that on. Since you are already using  `typeof`, you can use that on `v` as well. If we remain within the same example:

```
type Vehicle = {
    Registration: string
    Owner: string
    VehicleType: System.Type
}

let inline someComplexFun v  =
   let t = typeof<'v>
   let owner =  (^v: (member Owner: string)(v)) 
   let registration = (^v: (member Registration: string)(v))
   {Registration = registration; Owner = owner; VehicleType = t}
```

You could use `t` to identify which serializer to apply or extract it from the `VehicleType` field.

Comment: a lateral approach, an idea, what if I return JSON string directly from the function and handle serialization at the caller level, so don't have to worry about serialization as per type? (based on your comment above)

Comment: in essence, I'm thinking to make every web request function I've to to accept string and return string, and that's all http requests are about, string in and string out (JSON), what do you think?

Comment: Sure. You should give it a try. In a sense you are already doing it. Of course you're pushing the IO part of the operation to the edge but that's good. In a lot of cases the types are converted to something basic like string to serve as DTOs, so it's easy to serialize and deserialize. But you need to have validation once you convert back to a type, as working just with just strings can be a source of bugs. After all that's why the type system exist. :-) There are many different ways to approach the problem.

Comment: thanks for the encouragement. My idea is to return the string json from function, deserialize into type and manipulate, then pipe the serialized version back into the function, I'm working on this

Comment: Hi, I've another idea with using Generics, if I can have this solved -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597987/polymorphism-with-generics-and-common-fields