# Polymorphism with Generics and common fields

Tags: f#

Had this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49526861/polymorphism-with-types-for-common-fields) answered and is somewhat similar but this question requires using Generics while enforcing parameter type to have some common fields.

```
type Document = {
    Name: string
    Version: string
}

let inline requestData<'t> (document: 't) =
    Console.WriteLine(document.Name)
    Console.WriteLine(document.Version)
```

Test

```
requestData<Document>({Name = "test"; Version="259723983"})
```

The error I'm getting is

> Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constraint the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.

**Edit**

```
let inline requestData<'t> (document: 't) =
    let name = (^document: (member Name: string)(document))
```

> The declared type parameter `t'` cannot be used here since the type parameter cannot be resolved at compile time.

Comment: [Statically resolved type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters)

Comment: `requestData` should work the same as with `someComplexFun` in the answer you linked - you just need to declare the statically resolved member access instead of calling `document.Name` directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to constrain on the type not the document parameter. Also, the `'T` notation is for  the usual generics, not SRTP. If you insist on adding the type parameter (not sure why), this is how you can define it:

```
let inline requestData< ^a when ^a : (member Name : string)  > x =
    Console.WriteLine(^a: (member Name: string)(x))
```

This way you can write this:

```
open System

type Document = {
    Name: string
    Version: string
}

type OtherDoc = {
    Name: string
    Version: string
}

let doc1 = {Document.Name = "Joe"; Version = "123"}
let doc2 = {OtherDoc.Name = "Jim"; Version = "456"}

requestData doc2
requestData doc1
```

Or:

```
requestData<Document> doc1 //Joe
requestData<OtherDoc> doc2 //Jim
```

This will be an error:

```
requestData<Document> doc2 //error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type...
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. yes, I've learned that I can't use type constraints with generics